# Junction table between few tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I've 4 tables in my database,

I'm trying to build a page, that when the user select a jobs from different categories, it will appear in their JobCart page. 
is my Design for MyJobCart Table is correct ?? although I added some column in it !! . is the query to do this Job is just insertion query to MyJobCart Table ??

```
[Account Table]
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------+
| StudentID    | FirstName   | LastName | Email   | 
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------+
| 0            |    xxxx     | xxxx     | xxxx    |  
| 1            |    xxxx     | xxxx     | xxxx    |          
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------+



[Jobs Table]
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-----------------+------------+
| JobID        | Name        | description| numberOfJob     | dueDate    | 
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-----------------+------------+
| 0            |    xxxx     | xxxx       |     xxxx        |            |
| 1            |    xxxx     | xxxx       |     xxxx        |            |  
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-----------------+-----------+


[MyJobCart Table]
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------+---------+-------+
| No(primary)  | JobID(F-Key)       | StudentId(f-Key)| statusOfJob | 
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------+---+-----+-------+
| 0            |    xxxx            | xxxx            |    xxxx     | 
| 1            |    xxxx            | xxxx            |    xxxx     |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------+---+-------+
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking us?

Comment: sorry I fixed the typo